# PHP run interactive exe with entering parameters while running

Tags: php, linux

First of all sorry for my bad English. I tried to ask before here but not got any help. I tried to play by myself and solved half of my problems, but not all. I simply can't find any info on the net, because nobody did this as I understand..

Idea: web page where you can code, compile and run c++ code, let's call it web c++ compiler & debugger.

Solution:

1. Code written in **textarea** is sent to server
2. Server creates empty file called **main.cpp**
3. Server writes **$response->code** to previously created **main.cpp** file
4. Server compiles it by sending PHP command **shell_exec(g++ main.cpp)**
5. After this, **a.exe** file appears (our compiled program)

Let's imagine **main.cpp** content. If it is simply program which couts something and closes, I can use whatever, exec(), popen(), proc_exec(), system(), passthru()...

```
int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Hello world"; 
    return 0;
}
```

```
$descriptorspec = [0 => ["pipe", "r"], 1 => ["pipe", "w"], 2 => ["pipe", "w"]];
$process = proc_open(".../a.exe"), $descriptorspec, $pipes, getcwd());
$compiler_output = fread($pipes[1], 8192);
```

compiler_output returns **"Hello world"**, all fine. Next, if you want to pass arguments, let's imagine:

```
int main() 
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    std::cout << "a is equal to " << a; 
    return 0;
}
```

I am doing this:

```
$descriptorspec = [0 => ["pipe", "r"], 1 => ["pipe", "w"], 2 => ["pipe", "w"]];
$process = proc_open(".../a.exe"), $descriptorspec, $pipes, getcwd());

fwrite($pipes[0], "777\r\n"); // sending input parameter to STDIN

$compiler_output = fread($pipes[1], 8192);
```

compiler_output appears to be: **a is equal to 777**

PROBLEM: if program has unknown number of arguments to be entered (example: infinite while loop ... cin >> newVariable; till break), PHP page will spin infinite till get timeout. Is there a way to make something like:

```
$process = proc_open(".../a.exe"), $descriptorspec, $pipes, getcwd());

while (true) {
    if output waits for input:
        echo output
        send input to STDIN of program
    }
}
```

or let's imagine dialog:

Program **output**: please enter your name:

Program **input**: Test

Program **output**: enter your age:

Program **input**: Number

Program **output**: ....

As I found info, proc_exec waits till process end, so it can't be used to read output instantly while app is still running. I know, there are options to run Linux VM in browser for this to make "Live linux compiler" but it is too difficult for me. https://github.com/copy/v86

Any ideas how my problem can be solved? I need advice not code.. Thanks in advance. Maybe it is possible to make .sh script as an API which will run process and send info to user, or connect other libraries..? I don't want to give up

UPDATE: seems I need to use flush command! I have luck spinning while (true) loop with proc_open.

Without using flush: page is loading till timeout
With using flush: while loop now returns output and can make input!

Now I need to make few if's and will solve and post answer here.

Comment: It is indeed common for standard libraries to buffer output when stdout is not a TTY. The cleanest solution is to make the program flush manually at the end of each logical message. If you need to talk to programs you can't modify, there are hacks/tools like `stdbuf` and `unbuffer`, but they should be a last resort.

Comment: Are you sure about the [no one](https://www.google.com/search?q=compile+and+test+c%2B%2B+programs+in+browser+online+free&rlz=1C5CHFA_enNZ971NZ972&sxsrf=APwXEddSPpEQjcNn1U2-bkmJWYB_cKZawA%3A1681426598077&ei=pog4ZNOzBKnF4-EPgbGI8AM&oq=compile+and+test+c%2B%2B+programs+in+browser+free)?

Comment: @tink those are made not by PHP